# Query EntityManager To Obtain Entity Relationships

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

The entity manager should have a information all JPA entities and relationships for the system. Is there a way to generically query for all relationships for an entity? Ideally we would like to also retrieve information on both sides of a relationship even without the back link.

I went through the EntityManager API and originally thought maybe the EntityGraphs would return the information I was looking for. However, it appears are only returned if defined in the entities instead of generated by entity manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to introspect the information about entities.
Use JPA Metamodel API to do that.

To give you a gist:

```java
Metamodel metamodel = em.getMetamodel();
//Get a specific entity information
EntityType<MyEntity> typeMyEntity = metamodel.entity(MyEntity.class);

// Get all the entity classes:
Set<EntityType> allEntityTypes = metamodel.getEntities();

// Get all the attributes - including inherited:
Set<Attribute> attributes1 = typeMyEntity.getAttributes();
```

Comment: The Hibernate Metamodel was just what I was looking for. Thanks